# Error (Xcode): Framework 'Flutter' not found

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart

While I am trying to run my flutter app in ios simulator I am getting this error

Error (Xcode): Framework 'Flutter' not found

In case of android it is working fine.

I am using the latest Xcode and flutter SDK.

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                            9.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Framework 'Flutter' not found

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro.

Exited (1).

I tried reinstall xocde